# 'Profile Metatype' for BPMN2.0::DataObject not retained while csv import

Tags: enterprise-architect

Screen shot [DataObjects Diagram from EA side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRNpy.png)

```html
Name;Type;Notes;Phase;Version;Status;Priority;Complexity;Stereotype;Keywords;Language;Author;Scope;Alias;Is Abstract;Is Leaf;Is Root;Is Specification;Created Date;Modified Date;Requirement Difficulty;Requirement Priority;GenFile;Profile Metatype;GUID
TEST CSV;Artifact;;1.0;1.0;Updated;;1;DataObject;Project:;Java;Neha;Public;;0;0;0;0;12.06.2017 17:15;12.06.2017 17:15;;;;BPMN::DataObject;{4B212FF3-5AC7-472a-BBF5-2BB71D492276}
TEST CSV;Artifact;;1.0;1.0;Updated;;1;DataObject;Project:;Java;Neha;Public;;0;0;0;0;12.06.2017 17:15;12.06.2017 17:16;;;;BPMN2.0::DataObject;{D693F7BC-0124-4dd0-8469-55E9E8968286}
```

I'm trying to import a set of Data Objects from csv file into Enterpise Architect. It seems that even after specifying the Profile Metatype as 'BPMN2.0::DataObject' in the csv file, the object imported is of BPMN type and not BPMN2.0::DataObject. 
PS: The Type of the object is 'Artifact' and Stereotype is 'DataObject'.

I'm guessing its a bug.

Screen shot
[DataObjects created diagram from Project Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmpmU.jpg)

Here are the results, so I exported a data object and imported the same csv. If you look at the Last cell info shows the Profile Metatype. For export its BPMN2.0 and import is BPMN.

1. (From import) TEST CSV  Artifact 1.0    1.0 Updated 1   DataObject  Project: Java   Neha Public 0   0   0   0   12.06.2017 17:15    12.06.2017 17:15 **BPMN::DataObject**

   2. (From Export) TEST
      CSV Artifact    1.0 1.0 Updated 1   DataObject  Project: Java   Neha
      Public  0   0   0   0   12.06.2017 17:15    12.06.2017 17:16    **BPMN2.0::DataObject**

Comment: are you capable of importing a stereotype from another MDG?

Comment: Hmm I didn't try it. I have a BPMN 2.0 Model and I'm trying to import the Data Object which I'm able to manually insert from the GUI, also take an export of it in .csv but when I import it , its Profile Metatype changes. I'm quiet new to Enterprise Architect probably I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I just tried and it imported as exported. Just the tagged values are missing, which is what has to be expected. Try it in a blank model and inspect t_xref. That will show the stereotype in full length.

Comment: @ThomasKilian did you have to specify the MDG namespace as Neha did? ( "BPMN2.0::DataObject")

Comment: @Hue I created an BPMN2.0::DataObject, exported it and re-imported that.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I think she wants to import it from the csv, without it existing in the ea repository prior to the import

Comment: Here are the results, so I exported a data object and imported the same csv. If you look at the Last cell info shows the Profile Metatype. For export its BPMN2.0 and import is BPMN. 

1. (From import) TEST CSV Artifact  1.0 1.0 Updated  1 DataObject Project:  Java Neha  Public  0 0 0 0 12.06.2017 17:15 12.06.2017 17:15    BPMN::DataObject

2. (From Export) TEST CSV Artifact  1.0 1.0 Updated  1 DataObject Project:  Java Neha  Public  0 0 0 0 12.06.2017 17:15 12.06.2017 17:16    BPMN2.0::DataObject

Comment: put that in the question, comment formatting makes this really hard to read

Comment: I specify 'Profile Metatype' as BPMN2.0 although it somehow doesn't seem to accept it.

Comment: Sorry .. I realized after I saw my comment . I've added the screen shot and the csv data.

Comment: Please attach your csv

Comment: I attached it in the HTML tag since I was not able to attach a csv in Stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Also attached the side by side screen shots of the Dataobjects properties windows

Comment: seems like you cannot change the stereotype namespace of an already existing element, however for bpmn there exists a facility to migrate from version 1 to 2: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/domain_based_models/migrate_bpmn_1_1_model_to_bpmn.html

Comment: Your csv has one BPMN and one BPMN2.0 element. Of course these will result in BPMN and BPMN2.0 elements when imported.

Comment: @Hue thanks ... I will try that out. I think that should be it.

Comment: @Thomas I'm sorry I think I was not clear in describing. Actually I created a bpmn 2.0 dataobject using interface then exported and then imported the csv back into EA but without GUID that's why I have two data object. I exported it again to show the difference that the same element when imported without changing the property gives another stereotype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have turned off BPMN 1.0 when creating any BPMN types. You eventually might get mixed up:

[image]

It *is* possible to turn on BPMN 1.x *and* 2.0 but that leads to such cases you experience. Best is to remove the unneeded MDG files from EA's program folder `MDGTechnologies`. Just place those you don't need in another folder you might call `MDGTechnologies disabled`.

Comment: I see. I will do so. Thanks a lot!!